# Wp admin page isnt working

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

i installed wordpress on namecheap host and when i try to log in into my wp-admin page i get this error 324:

[image]

Comment: your site front-end is working or not?

Comment: Are you using the right address? Is everything ok with you domain?